# Flask- SQLAlchemy- Advanced Search using Filter

Tags: flask, html-select, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

I am using a series of filters and html select dropdowns to try and create an advanced search.  I would like the user to be able to select various fields that they want to search by and get results. I can get the "search" (i.e. a complex filter) to work if I only have 4 fields active for 'query' in views.py below, but more than four fields returns no results because no records meet all of filters field values.  Which I knew would happen.

So I have been trying to figure out how to create a "--All--" option so that a user can choose which attributes they are most interested, and which attributes they want "query" to ignore.

views.py (truncated version-have several more fields to search on)

```
from flask import render_template, redirect, session, url_for, request, send_from_directory
from sqlalchemy import or_, and_, select
from flask.ext.security import login_required
from datetime import datetime
from RestorationPlantDB import app, db
from RestorationPlantDB import SPECIES, SPInfo, SPRef, Role, User

@app.route('/search_advanced', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def search_advanced():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        stratum = request.form.get('stratum')
        origin = request.form.get('origin')


        query = SPInfo.query.filter(and_(SPInfo.Stratum == stratum, 
                                         SPInfo.Origin == origin))

    return render_template('result_advancedsearch.html', year=datetime.now().year, query=query)

return render_template('search_advanced.html', year=datetime.now().year)

@app.route('/result_advancedsearch', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def result_advancedsearch():

    return render_template('result_advancedsearch.html', year=datetime.now().year)
```

search_advanced.html

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block content %}

<div class="container">

    <h1>Advanced Search</h1>

    <form method="POST" action="search_advanced">          
           <div class="advanced">
               <!--Select species stratum-->
               <label for="stratum"><p class="advanced">Lifeform</p></label>
               <select name="stratum" id="stratum">
                   <option value= ""> -- All -- </option>  <!-- Need to figure out how to pass an all option-->
                   <option value="Graminoid">Graminoid</option>
                   <option value="Forb">Forb</option>
                   <option value="Subshrub">Sub-Shrub</option>
                   <option value="Shrub">Shrub</option>
                   <option value="Tree">Tree</option>
                   <option value="Vine">Vine</option>
               </select>
           </div>

           <div class="advanced">
               <!--Select species origin-->
               <label for="origin"><p class="advanced">Origin</p></label>
               <select name="origin" id="origin">
                   <option value=""> -- All -- </option>  <!-- Need to figure out how to pass an all option-->
                   <option value="Native">Native</option>
                   <option value="Exotic">Exotic</option>
               </select>
            </div>

 </form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using SQLAlchemy you can conditionally build the query based on the available parameters. Essentially you can apply `filter()`, `filter_by()` or any other query method as many times as you need to and SQLAlchemy will figure out how to build the query.

```
query = SPInfo.query
if stratum:
    query = query.filter(SPInfo.Stratum == stratum)
if origin:
    query = query.filter(SPInfo.Origin == origin)
if elev:
    query = query.filter(SPInfo.Elevation.contains(elev))

results = query.all()
```

For cleaner code you'd want to construct a list of the elements to test how to apply those filters and then use a loop to do the above.

Comment: @ PJ Santoro  Thanks!  I have to play with it a bit but I just did a quick test and it looks like it is working!

Comment: Great, glad I could help!